# How to crop background image to be used in overlay?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i hinh1.jpg -i 2.mp4 \
       -filter_complex "[1]scale=iw/2.5:-1[ovrl]; \
        [0][ovrl]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2:shortest=1[v],\
        pan=stereo|c0<c0+0*c1|c1<c0+0*c1,aeval=val(0)|-val(1)" \
       -map "[v]" -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 -g 60 -b:v 2500k \
       -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -preset ultrafast tap2.mp4
```

**Current output**:

[image]

I need to insert -filter:v "crop=in_w:in_h-360", so it looks like this

**Desired output**:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Common mistake some members make is formatting. Please do not just paste in code and expect us to know what you want. Taking a minute to [edit] your question to make it easier to read will increase your chances of getting the help you seek.

Answer (score 0):

The background image has to be cropped before being used in overlay

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i hinh1.jpg -i 2.mp4 \
   -filter_complex "[1]scale=iw/2.5:-1[ovrl]; \
    [0]crop=in_w:in_h-360[bg]; \
    [bg][ovrl]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2:shortest=1[v],\
    [1]pan=stereo|c0<c0+0*c1|c1<c0+0*c1,aeval=val(0)|-val(1)[a]" \
   -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 -g 60 -b:v 2500k \
   -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -preset ultrafast tap2.mp4
```

If you need to pad the image back to its original height, use

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i hinh1.jpg -i 2.mp4 \
   -filter_complex "[1]scale=iw/2.5:-1[ovrl]; \
    [0]crop=in_w:in_h-360,pad=iw:ih+360:0:180[bg]; \
    [bg][ovrl]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2:shortest=1[v],\
    [1]pan=stereo|c0<c0+0*c1|c1<c0+0*c1,aeval=val(0)|-val(1)[a]" \
   -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 -g 60 -b:v 2500k \
   -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -preset ultrafast tap2.mp4
```